# Has Apple removed the requirement for backward compatibility for app update

Tags: ios, app-store

One of our app originally support `armv6`, and now we can update a new version only support `armv7` and `armv7s` and update the `deployment target` to 4.3.

So now has Apple removed the requirement for backward compatibility for app update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Apple has removed support for that. It had already started in ios5 itself where they removed it

> In Xcode 4.3 Apple had already removed the armv6 setting from the ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT

But if you still want to do it then you will need to build against older ios than ios6, but then you will not be able to build for `armv7s` . I would suggest not doing it.

Here is the link how to go about doing it. Please take it with a grain of salt.
[Link](http://blog.chpwn.com/post/31824877081)

Answer (score 0):

As S. P. said, there is no support for armv6 now.

The thing is, you need to use Xcode 4.5 not so much for using armv7s but to build agains iOS 6 and to support the new iPhone 5. I mean, you can build and ship for the iPhone 5 without using armv7s at all, in fact is recommended since not many devs have an iPhone 5 at hand to test and because of many libraries fail building agains it.

Thing is, if you use Xcode 4.4.x, you will still be able to ship to armv6 devices and iOS 4.x < 4.3, but you won't be able to use any iOS 6 feature (your rotation will be completely broke, as a consequence) and forget about supporting the new iPhone 5's screen.

So Apple's decision force us to stop supporting older devices and older versions (old being 3, 4 years). There is nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

A developer can not add UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities restrictions to an app's plist for required hardware for an app that is already in the App store, as that would restrict backwards compatibility.

But a developer can raise the Minimum Deployment target up to the very latest released iOS version (6.0 currently), or anything in-between (4.3 is the lowest supported by Xcode 4.5).

If an iOS device no longer supports the required OS version (armv6 devices can't run iOS 6.x, or 4.3), then it is Apple that is limiting backward compatibility, not you, the app developer, or the app itself.  So youR app will meet the requirement, and Apple has recently been approving **tons** of apps that do so (check the updates for all the raised minimum deployment targets).